# Django username field nullable breaks default auth backend

Tags: django, django-authentication

when using a custom User model, extending `AbstractBaseUser`, I've run into a problem when the USERNAME_FIELD points to a nullable field

what I'm trying to accomplish is to allow multiple methods of login (facebook, username) and for that I have two unique identifier fields (facebook_id, username) but both have to be nullable because an account doesn't have to have both (and most accounts won't have both)

so for logging in with username, I rely on Django's built in login auth backend

where it falls apart is when trying to log in with an alternative login method (facebook) and the Django auth is attempted first

```
class ModelBackend(object):
    """
    Authenticates against settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    """

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
```

the `if username is None` hack is meant to fix the situation where the username field isn't actually called "username" so the `username` parameter is empty but the actual provided username can be found in `kwargs`

the issue is that it ends up with None value anyway (because kwargs contains facebook_id=12345) and ends up passing that to `get_by_natural_key`

```
def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
```

which translates roughly to `User.objects.get(username=None)`

since my username field is nullable, this returns multiple results, the whole thing throws an models.MultipleObjectsReturned exception ("get() returned more than one User -- it returned 417!") and prevents any other auth backends from running

from my perspective there's several issues:

1. ModelBackend shouldn't be just blindly attempting to retrieve a user if its attempts at figuring out the provided username result with `None`
2. get_by_natural_key should catch the MultipleObjectsReturned and gracefully fail, or authenticate() should handle that scenario and fail to log the user in, instead of bombing the entire auth mechanism

known workarounds:

I know I can move the ModelBackend to be the last method attempted but that just makes the dumb query run sometimes instead of always, I'd rather fix it so it never does. I'm also slightly concerned with its performance as number of username=None users grows

I also know I can extend ModelBackend, patch the holes and just not use the stock ModelBackend, but I don't know if there are any gotchas to that approach... are existing sessions using ModelBackend lost?

For simplification purposes, I skipped the part where I actually use a nullable email field as the username :D and I know that for that I could just easily use a custom auth backend but once I got nullable-email-field-login working I started thinking I can probably save myself some headache in generating usernames for users coming from facebook (and letting them choose an unused username later on in the process) by making username field nullable as well :D

I'm concerned that having a nullable USERNAME_FIELD is going to make Django fail in various different ways, and I saw no warning for this or explanation for why. It's silly that a system that supports multiple login schemes cannot survive it's stock auth identifier being empty.

Comment: Why don't you simply use something like https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth?

Comment: @BerislavLopac I knew I forgot the "please don't suggest auth packages as solution" line...

Comment: I thought you might have, that's why I put a comment instead of an answer. Say hi to Penny! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're replacing the default `User` model with your own, I'd go with patching its manager's `get_by_natural_key` method to raise `DoesNotExist` when called with a `None` natural key, as that situation clearly indicates your user is being authenticated using some other scheme. Your model has no situation where a record can have a legitimate `None` natural key, so in any case it should raise a `DoesNotExist` for such a key.

Comment: this indeed fixes the issue... I wonder if it's worth submitting as a Django bug? leaving open for a bit more to see if any other responses come in

Comment: I don't see this as a Django bug. This is a peculiarity of your specific replacement for the `User` model, and as such it is your responsibility to support Django's authentication model, not vice-versa. Granted, Django's authentication model is not the most flexible API in the world, but in this specific case the fix clearly belongs in your model, not theirs.

Comment: I think it should either be documented ("username field has to be unique and cannot be null") or handled :)

Comment: Go ahead and submit a bug report then. You don't need me to agree whether this is a bug or not.

Comment: It's partially there: according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD, "The field must be unique (i.e., have unique=True set in its definition)." It doesn't explicitly states that it should not be nullable, and I agree that it would be preferred, but IMO a nullable field can't really be considered unique.

Comment: @BerislavLopac: unique=True implies database uniqueness, NULL != NULL in database world, so the records are unique

Comment: I know the theory, that's why I said "IMO" -- should have said "from my point of view, for all practical purposes". ;-)
But yeah, the docs should be updated.